# Generate a token for authentication via URL grails spring security rest plugin

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have a Grails app with spring security rest plugin that handles the authorization.

Now, besides basic scenario of authorizing through login endpoint, I want to be able to generate tokens on my own and send them within URL's.

On top of that, I want them to start expiring only after the link was clicked.

I already went through this article, but couldn't find anything useful for me
http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it can be done by by isung [TokenGenerator](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/gapi/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/generation/TokenGenerator.html)

Simply call 'generateAccessToken' method and pass GrailsUser as a param

Hope that helps